# Copy rows from one table to another and make a relationship of many to many

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Sample Tables (I don't mess with users, This is just a sample)

```
-ImportUsers
--Name

-Users
--Id
--Name
-Roles
--Id
--Title
-UsersToRoles
--UserId
--RoleId
```

How to copy from 'ImportUsers' to 'Users' with one role the admin specified?

P.s.
I saw this [link](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLSelectInsert.aspx), but this can't help in this situation.

Comment: Could you use SSIS? Is the best way to handle this. http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2684/importing-sql-server-data-using-ssis--which-option-is-fastest/

Comment: Can you post some sample data? How/what information do you want to be inserted in the other tables, if you have only `Name` in ImportUsers?

Comment: @Radu Gheorghiu Simple as that - only the Name

Comment: @Thiago Custodio - Can I call it by code?

Comment: @yytg yes, http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Calling-a-SSIS-Package-a35afefb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tables and data

```
create table ImportUsers (Name varchar(15))
create table Users (Id int identity(1,1), name varchar(15))
create table Roles (Id int identity(1,1), title varchar(15))
create table UsersToRoles(UserId int, RoleId int)

insert roles values('Admin')

insert ImportUsers values('Thomas')
```

Script to insert data

```
create table #t(id int)

--merge to ensure names will remain unique(I am assuming that is a requirement)
;MERGE INTO Users t1 
using ImportUsers t2 on t1.name = t2.name
when not matched then INSERT (Name)   
VALUES( t2.Name ) 
OUTPUT Inserted.id
INTO #t;

insert UsersToRoles (UserId, RoleId )
select t.id, r.id from #t t
join roles r
on r.Title = 'Admin'

drop table #t
--consider: delete from ImportUsers
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that ID is an identity in users and that the admin role exists in roles and there are no existing users, something like

```
insert into users( name ) 
select name from ImportUsers

insert into UsersToRoles ( UserID, RoleID ) 
select users.id , role.id 
from users, roles
where role.name = 'admin'
```